# TCL Asking User for Multiple Inputs

Tags: tcl, user-input

I am trying to ask a user multiple questions so that a machine may make parts according to the inputs. The inputs are to be saved as variables to be called later in the program. I have written the below code and request help in understanding why it does not run. I am getting errors with the puts command as well as the program not waiting for a response after each question. As you can see I am new to this and would be grateful for any pointers you can provide. Thank you in advance.

```
    #Asks user for diameter of probe
    flush stdout;
    puts “Enter Diameter ”
    gets stdin diameter
    #Asks user for Taper Length of probe
    flush stdout;
    puts “Enter Taper Length ”
    gets stdin taper
    #Asks user for tip shape of probe
    flush stdout;
    puts “Enter Tip Shape s=sharp, r=radius and f=flat”
    gets stdin shape
    # Prompt for tip size
    flush stdout;
    if {r} {
    puts “Enter Radius Size ”
    gets stdin radius
    } elseif {d}{
    puts “Enter Diameter Size”
    gets stdin diameter
    }
```

Comment: Are those stylized quote marks from your program or from the copy-paste process?  Those quote marks would not be valid in a program.

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting? The messages are important if we are to help you.

Comment: wrong # args: should be "puts ?-nonewline? ?channelId? string"
    while executing
"puts “Enter Diameter ”"
    invoked from within
"interp eval $::tkcon::OPT(exec) $args"
    (procedure "::tkcon::EvalSlave" line 2)
    invoked from within
"EvalAttached [list source $fn]"
    (procedure "::tkcon::Load" line 18)
    invoked from within

Comment: The prior message shows the type of errors I am getting when I try to run the program. I am running this in TKCON from ActiveTCL. The quotation marks were used because the puts command requires them when trying to display more than one word, right?

Comment: I think Brad was on to something. The quoting character is a simple ASCII double quote character (e.g  "This is quoted"). The stylized forward and backward quote marks in your question will not work. The error message indicates that since it detected too many arguments.

Comment: It was determined that because the quotes were written using MS Word they were the incorrect type which lead to the error. This was rectified by deleting them and adding quotes in Notepad ++. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It was determined that because the quotes were written using MS Word they were the incorrect type which lead to the error. This was rectified by deleting them and adding quotes in Notepad++. The if statement was also corrected using (`if {$shape == "r"}`) and (`elseif {$shape == "f"}`). Thank you for your help.